# Autorefresh some list of items every X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items that I want to refresh every X seconds. Basically these list of items may be some data coming from database that meets a certain criteria. Now I could very well do this using setTimeout or setInterval and then manually calling `$.ajax` and set the html of div or something. However is there any plugin available for the same? I guess it would be better to use that in terms of extensibility and also in terms of UI.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i use `setInterval(methodname,interval)` to do this - no need for a plugin to write a single line of code

Comment: @ManseUK: Ok so far, but how about the ajax query und the reload of the list?

Comment: I don't see how a plugin would be better for UI and extensibility than `setInterval(fn, 10000);`, unless there is some other functionality your trying to achieve?

Comment: @PiTheNumber with the information presented by the OP - thats my answer - there is no example of how complex the list is, where it originally comes from, how its presented etc

Comment: @Jaggu - if you give us some more information then perhaps we can expand on our answers - can you include your html - tell us how the list is originally created - how it looks ?

Comment: I need good UI like http://www.pivotaltracker.com/. It is basically project management tool and has very nice listing of items. But you unfortunately you can't access it. You may have to create account on that which may not be feasible for you.

Comment: Im sorry if everyone feels like im having a rant - but seriously the question (at least to me) is more about asking how to refresh a list rather than how it should look ...

Comment: @Jaggu you can create pictures on here too ... or at least create a http://jsfiddle.net/ to show us what you have so far - ie the first creation of the menu before its refreshed

Comment: Did you pay attention to facebook? It has the same listing feature on the right side where your friends update are posted in a nicely formatted manner that keeps moving up and refreshing every few seconds. I am trying to achieve the same.

Comment: @Jaggu - then put that in your question

Comment: Your original question about how to refresh the data has been answered. How to design your UI is not a question for stack overflow. I'd suggest posting it on http://ux.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not just me then !?!?!

Comment: @ManseUK No, not at all.

Comment: @Rory: My question is not how to redesign the UI. I need the plugin that already has nice UI design. There is a difference between the two. I have already posted about my requirement of good UI in my original question.

Comment: @Jaggu - if you showed us what it is mean to to look like perhaps we can advise on how to change it .... UI with any pictures or examples is very hard

Comment: I would advise that you expand your question because you're not providing enough information for anyone to realistically help you. This usually leads to a protracted and frustrating round of requests in the comments for more information by other users who **really do want to help you**. For example, include in the question: code snippets/samples, the API you're using, stack traces, screen shots etc. When you've done this, flag to have your question re-opened. Please also take the time to [read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's really one line with `setInterval`, so it would actually probably be more work to use a plugin.  If you need an example, [check one out](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/2009/02/26/jquery-auto-refresh-div-every-x-seconds/).

If you need help with the Ajax, check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Apparently you are looking for something like a "Loading..." plugin to display while the list is refreshed?  In that case, checkout out the [jQuery loading plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/loading).

Comment: I've already posted in my question that I know this technique. However I need some nice UI. If I do it this way it will look very boring.

Comment: Well without seeing your HTML, it's hard to tell what the UI would look like.  The basic functionality is done this way, however.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
setInterval(methodname,interval);
```

to do this - no need for a plugin to write a single line of code

if you want to tame lists [click here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/) (A list apart)

Comment: But I need that nice UI that plugin offers. I am not good at UI. You know those nice rounded corners or something.

Comment: @Jaggu - you just said "I have a list of items" you never mentioned how they are displayed - if you ask the whole question at the start you get better answers .....

Comment: But while posting I already mentioned that I know this technique. Did you read it?

Comment: @Jaggu yes I read the question - you asked "However is there any plugin available for the same?" right after "I could very well do this using setTimeout or setInterval and then manually calling $.ajax and set the html of div or something."

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` should work fine, however if you're dead-set on using a plugin, you could consider Prototype's PeriodicalExecuter or PeriodicalUpdater.

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/periodicalExecuter

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/periodicalUpdater

A benefit of using the PeriodicalUpdater is the polling time will grow longer as the same response keeps coming back, saving on data transfer cost.